# Can't assign function output to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called locations that looks like:

```
Home Number       Workplace Number      Year
A                 D                     1998
B                 H                     2001
C                 F                     2012
D                 O                     2005
```

I already created a network graph using 'Home Number'. Here I want to calculate the smallest path length between Home and Workplace, according to the Home network. For a given Home and Workplace, I can plug them into the following function:

```
def get_path_length(home_id, workplace_id):
    if home_id in nodes:
        try:
            path_length = nx.shortest_path(G, source = home_id, target = workplace_id)   
            print(path_length)
        except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
            path_length = -8888
    else:
        path_length = -9999
    return(path_length)
```

The problem arises when I apply the same function to each row in the dataframe, and then store the result in a column called 'Path Length'. I tried the following:

```
location_data = locations[['Home Number','Workplace Number']]

locations['Path Length'] = location_data.apply(get_path_length,axis=1)
```

But I got an error:

```
TypeError: ("get_path_length() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Workplace Number'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I have also tried to iterate over each row:

```
for index, row in locations.iterrows():
    locations[index,'Path Length'] = get_judge_path(row['Home Number'],row['Workplace Number'])
```

But then get the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass 2 columns in lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: get_path_length(x['Home Number'], x['Workplace Number'])
locations['Path Length'] = locations.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for the suggestion. Is there any reason that I have to use "lambda x" for two columns, but directly applying the function works just fine if there is only one columns?

Comment: I used your original code and it gives exactly what I want.

Comment: @Tian - It is up to you, what columns names are specified, you can also pass 10 columns.

Comment: @Tian - btw, filtering is not necessary, working nice `locations['Path Length'] = locations.apply(f, axis=1)`

Comment: This makes sense! No filtering makes the code cleaner. Thanks a lot for all the help!